# Jquery Height issue

Tags: jquery

I have a page when It loads for the first time I want to add a div with Height 450px. The page have 3 submit buttons and when ever anyone clicks any of those 3 buttons I need to set the height to 0px.

Here is what I did.`

```
     <style type="text/css">

    .DivHeight
    {
        height:450px;
    }
    .DivNoHeight
    {
        height:0px;
    }

   </style>

                   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {

           document.getElementById("divHeight").className = "DivHeight";

          $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {


            document.getElementById("#divHeight").className = "DivNoHeight";
            alert("Test");

        });
    });
      </script>
```

But when I have the above code on page load It is displaying fine but when I click on Submit button the results are coming after 450px :(

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I am getting 450 PX height only if I add the class in the div Manually

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, You can use `$('#divHeight')` instead of `document.getElementById("divHeight")` and instead of native `.className` you can use `.addClass` function.

Comment: I changed it. No it didn't help Updating the question with more details please see one more time.

Comment: Is the ID of your element definitely `divHeight` and not `DivHeight`?

Comment: @SmilingLily It was a suggestion and not an answer. Please try those once after you have fixed what you had.

Comment: Could you show your (relevant) HTML as well? Also you have three submit-buttons, but you're only attaching a click-handler to the button with an `id` of `#btnSubmit`. ...unless all three buttons have that `id`, which would be invalid HTML.

Comment: @TimBJames: that stuff is all case insensitive.

Comment: @SmilingLily: look at your code. What do you see different between them? The answer is quite obvious if you look carefully.

Comment: Yes checked the case sensitivity.It's all good

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, I think the case-difference between `divHeight` and `DivHeight` is deliberate (in that one's an `id` and the other a class-name). ...unless you meant something else? (And if you did, I'm missing it too... =/ )

Comment: @ChrisMorgan javascript case insensitive?! you're having a laugh! If SmilingLily has accidentally typed `divHeight` instead of `DivHeight` then it will all go wrong.

Comment: @TimBJames My apologies; I had the notion that IDs were case insensitive. I see that I was wrong. Notion corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following jQuery:

```
var div = $('#divHeight');
div.addClass('DivHeight');

$('button[type="submit"],input[type="submit"]').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents actual submission
        div.toggleClass('DivHeight DivNoHeight');
        console.log(div.height());
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EpsFb/1/).

The demo using this HTML (adapt to your needs, of course):

```
<div id="divHeight">
</div>
<!-- ...other html... -->
<input type="submit" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>​
```

And this (or *similar*) CSS:

```
.DivHeight {
    background-color: #f90; // just for testing purposes
    height: 450px;
}

.DivNoHeight {
    background-color: #ffa; // just for testing purposes
    height: 0;
}​
```

This jQuery is based on the following assumptions:

1. You're trying to deal with an element that has an `id` equal to `divHeight`,
2. That you want the classes assigned to that `div` to control the height,
3. That you have multiple buttons, or inputs, of `type="submit"`,
4. That you don't want to submit the `form` (or whatever) on clicking the buttons, but in response to another event (validation success, for example).

---

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

The ready event is overwriting the submit.  Everytime you submit the ready event will be triggered after the page loads, therefore, always 450.

Find a better event to update the height.  I'm sure JQuery has some like beforeSubmit or complete.  Or try to get rid of the document ready and use that style class initially on the div then try with only the submit\onclick event.

Also, listen to Matthew Van Andel.  That's how JQuery should be coded.

Answer (score 0):

```
//On ready... (shorthand)
$(function(){

    //Load the div element.
    var myDiv = $("#divHeight");

    //Assign the height class to the div element
    myDiv.addClass("DivHeight");

    //Set a click event for the submit button
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //Remove height class from div element, set noheight class...
        myDiv.removeClass('DivHeight').addClass('DivNoHeight');
    });

});
```

You might want to consider using jQuery's .hide() method instead of juggling classes. Like so...

```
myDiv.hide();
```

It really depends on what you're going for. You could also use fadeOut() instead of hide() if you want to get really fancy ;-)

Comment: Can you update your example with the relevant HTML? Provided you have a document with exactly two elements, #divHeight and #btnSubmit, that code should work swimmingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply using

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#divHeight").addClass("DivHeight");
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    $("#divHeight").addClass("DivNoHeight");
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hwu7F/)** is the fiddle live demo.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple submit buttons, give them a common class and not an id. You can replace `$("#btnSubmit")` with `$(".btnSubmit")` then.

Answer (score 0):

You state you have three submit buttons but references the submit button with an id (`#btnSubmit`). As I know you can only have one element with one id. Set the class on each button to `class="btnSubmit"` instead and reference them by ".btnSubmit".

As you are using jQuery I would recommend using it instead of plain old docuemt.getElementById as jQuery is browser independent.

I would probably do something likte this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divHeight").addClass("DivHeight");
    $(".btnSubmit").click(function() {
        $("#divHeight").removeClass("DivHeight");
        $("#divHeight").addClass("DivNoHeight");
    });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: I said 3 buttons and I am testing the code out with one button.

Comment: Ok! I did not get that. I hope I could help in some way any how. I think you have found your answer with the page being reload on submit. Happy coding!